# Image classification with python (I want to delete the cropped image)

Tags: python, opencv, keras

I am Korean. I don't speak English very well. Sorry.
I want Python to classify images.
I want to delete the cropped image from the augmentation image(Rotate, enlarge, reduce, shear).
I think I would use a bounding box or keypoint for OpenCV.
Specifically I set a point from the original image, and I want to delete the image with the point cut off from the augmentation image.
[example. Point is cat ear and foot. The image with the ears and feet cut off is to be deleted.]
What should I use? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img1=cv2.imread("C:/Users/sourab/Desktop/1.jpg")
img2=cv2.imread("C:/Users/sourab/Desktop/2.jpg")
img1=cv2.resize(img1,(400,400))
img2=cv2.resize(img2,(400,400))
blackWD = np.zeros((400, 400,3), dtype="uint8")
corners = np.array([[50, 50], [200,50], [200, 200], [50, 200]])
cv2.fillPoly(blackWD,[corners],(255,255,255))
whiteWD = cv2.bitwise_not(blackWD)
whiteWD = cv2.bitwise_and(img1, whiteWD)
k=cv2.bitwise_and(blackWD,img2)
l=cv2.bitwise_or(whiteWD,k)

cv2.imshow("img1",img1)
cv2.imshow("img2",img2)
cv2.imshow("black",whiteWD)
cv2.imshow("k",k)
cv2.imshow("result",l)
```

Output:
[image]
do you want that type of code?